# 0 bytes free space windows 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have installed windows server 2008 R2 in one of my client Server. I have given 50 GB for C drive and 80 GB 120 GB for D and E drive Respectively. from the last one week I am facing one problem that C drive is showing zero '0' bytes free space. But all the files in C drive are 28 GB only. Requesting you to assist me in this. I have tried all the possible troubleshooting steps like :-

Disk Clean up
chkdsk
check for shadow copy. (No shadow copies in the server)

Comment: Is there a pagefile on the drive?

Comment: Did you check hidden files? Recycle bin? How did you find out it's 28 GB only?

Comment: If you can add some screenshots or output of `chkdsk` or similar, that might help the experts here.

Comment: Page file has taken from D drive. Mr Chris McKeown
Yep I have checked all the Hidden files by unchecking hide protected operating system files and checking show hidden files.. but no file is occupying more than 2 MB. Mr Pazis.

Comment: Requesting all the experts to help me in this.

Comment: @GopiKrishna TheCleaner asked you to put a `chkdsk`-output in your question (you can use [edit](http://serverfault.com/posts/565302/edit) for that). The reason for this is, we need to know how large the allocation units are, bad sectors, KB used by index etc.... (Also when doing a disk Cleanup, **never** **never** **never** check the box for "compress files")

Comment: Any Update on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for this:
The issue is with the MySQL Service. 
Temp folder for MYSQL folder has not defined and it was using the TEMP folder on the server.

Found the root cause in the blog : http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56347

Comment: Please your answer the checkmark so that it does not sit around for years without a resolution marked.

Comment: You uh realize that bug is for Linux right?

Answer (score 4):

You can try a tool like [Treesize free](http://www.jam-software.de/treesize_free/) which lists space used by folder. Works great when I have to find what is filling my drives. Be sure to run with high privileges.

Answer (score 1):

I had a server do this a few months ago but for the server's D drive. I used Windirstat (portable version) to scan the drive. Long story short it was volume shadowcopy taking up space even being disable as netbackup was configured to manually create shadowcopies and shadowcopies was configured to dump the shadowcopy from C to D and D to D so it filled up the D drive.

1. Could be Shadowcopies, does not hurt to double check. "vssadmin list shadowstorage" you can view them via command line or under "system properties" and "system protection" if you want GUI. GUI location is different from 2003
2. Could be in hidden folder from some application
3. Could be windows indexing
4. Could be your backup software

Comment: As it is a production server, I can not format it. Finally I found that two files are getting generated in Windows/Temp folder. Those are occupying complete free space in C Drive in my case it is 23 GB. If I delete one unwanted 100 MB file, with in secs it is occupying the 100 MB free space. Can any one suggest me how to get rid out of this ?

Comment: You should have a backup and restore plan for such an event. You better setup an outage window.